# How can I find solution and plot multi complex variable equation?

Tags: plotting, complex

I have an question about solving equation.

x and y are variable, and a, b, and c are complex constant.

The equations is formed like: $x^2/a - y^2/b = c$.

I want to contour plot a graph range from $x1 < Re(x) < x2$ to $y1 < Re(y) < y2$. 
$x1$, $x2$, $y1$, and $y2$ is real number even though $x$ and $y$ satisfied this equation are complex number.

I have used

```
ContourPlot[x^2/a - y^2/b == c, {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}]
```

However, because this considers only real case, I can't find a solution.

If anyone has a idea, please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this using [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html)?

```
SeedRandom[1]

{a, b, c} = RandomComplex[1 + I, 3];

ContourPlot[ReIm[x^2/a - y^2/b] == ReIm[c], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

If you are using an older version of *Mathematica* without `ReIm` define:

```
ReIm = Function[x, {Re@x, Im@x}, Listable];
```